# Unable to show UICollectionView menu in iOS8

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios8, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to make a UIMenu appear in a collection view.

I've setup my menu

```
UIMenuItem* deleteItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"DELETE", @"Supprimer") action:@selector(deleteShow:)];
UIMenuItem* archiveItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ARCHIVE", @"Archiver") action:@selector(archiveShow:)];
UIMenuItem* unarchiveItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"UNARCHIVE", @"Restaurer") action:@selector(unArchiveShow:)];

[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:@[deleteItem,archiveItem,unarchiveItem]];
```

And I've implemented the following methods in my Collection View Delegate :

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
```

The first two always returns YES.
But no menu is showing on long press. Not even the standard cut/copy/paste menu.
Anyone experienced something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Spent some time for this problem. Found that if you do not implement "deleteShow:" and etc. method in the UICollectionViewCell's subclass, the menu item would not show up.